# Faces Navigation not really working in JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, java-ee-6, faces-config

I'm using JSF 2.0

this is my faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file is not required if you don't need any extra configuration. -->
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/pages/test/test.html</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>write</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/test/test-write.html</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>

    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

The TestController.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="testController")
@SessionScoped
public class TestController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3244711761400747261L; 

    public String test() {


        return "write?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

in my test.xhtml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                    <h:commandButton action="#{testController.test()}" value="test" />  
            </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

and this is my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Bachelor Demo</display-name>      

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The view IDs should not contain the `FacesServlet` mapping. It should represent the physical file path/name. Change `.html` to `.xhtml`.
You should also remove `?faces-redirect=true` and instead add a `<redirect />` to the `<navigation-case>`.

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/pages/test/test.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>write</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/test/test-write.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

By the way, this is the old JSF 1.x style. Are you aware of the new JSF2 implicit navigation? You could just return `"/pages/test/test-write.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"`.

```
public String test() {
    return "/pages/test/test-write.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

No need for bloated XML navigation cases anymore.

Further, if your action method is really not doing anything else, then you can also just put exactly that return value in the `action` attribute instead.

```
<h:commandButton ... action="/pages/test/test-write.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
```

Even more, if it's plain page-to-page navigation, rather use `<h:link>` instead. It's more SEO friendly as searchbots don't index POST forms:

```
<h:link ... outcome="/pages/test/test-write.xhtml" />
```

Comment: hi @BalusC, i tried both - i changed it to .xhmtl in the navigationrule - it was not working. i also deleted the navigation rule and used the `"/pages/test/test-write.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"` is the `faces-config.xml` and the `web.xml` right?

Comment: If the rule didn't work then the from view ID just didn't match. You can learn about it by examing `facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId()` in the action method. Note that I updated my answer with the suggestion to remove `?faces-redirect`. Further I'm not sure if I understand your last question. That string is supposed to be just the `return` value of the action method.

Comment: Oh, the action would not be invoked at all then. You could have figured that out by setting a breakpoint on the action method or by adding a sysout/logger line. By the way, if the action method doesn't contain anything else than just a return value for naviation, then you can also just put exactly that return value inside the `action` attribute instead. Even more, if it's pure page-to-page navigation, rather use `<h:link outcome="..." />` instead w/o redirect. That's more SEO friendly. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink

Comment: thanks... and thats how i found it at the end... i feel so stupid

Comment: by returning the file name from the method, aren't you coupling the the view and controller?  I mean the guy coding the method has to tell the guy writing the .xhtml page what to name it?  For guys like me trying to wear both hats, I guess it doesn't matter !